# Is there any way to check to see if a VBScript function is defined?

Tags: function, asp-classic, vbscript, defined

This is probably just wishful thinking...

Is there any way to check to see if an ASP/VBScript function is defined before calling it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is my solution which works on the same principle, but the hacky-ness is pretty self-contained:

```
Function FunctionExists( func_name )
    FunctionExists = False 

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim f : Set f = GetRef(func_name)

    If Err.number = 0 Then
        FunctionExists = True
    End If  
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: Yeah - that's what I ended up doing with it.  :-)

Comment: You could simplify this to `FunctionExists = (Err.Number = 0)` to set the `Boolean`.

Comment: @Lankymart, doesn't work the same.  Not sure why not.

Comment: Can simplify to: If Err.number = 0 Then FunctionExists = True

Answer (score 6):

It's a slightly hacky way to do it as it relies on having set "On Error Resume Next", but you could do something like this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim objRef1, objRef2
Set objRef1 = GetRef("DoStuff1")
If objRef1 Is Nothing Then
    Call objRef1
Else
    MsgBox "DoStuff1 is not defined!"
End If

Set objRef2 = GetRef("DoStuff2")
If objRef2 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "DoStuff2 is not defined!"
Else
    Call objRef2
End If

Sub DoStuff1
    MsgBox "DoStuff1!"
End Sub
```

The call to GetRef will generate an exception if the sub or function you're trying to get a pointer to does not exist (as is the case here with DoStuff2). You can then check if the reference was set as expected.

Comment: Otherwise you're into checking Err.Number after trying to call the function. But then the function you're calling may be defined, get called, but be the source of the error, which I guess is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The provided answers are correct, I just made a simple modification by adding `Err.Clear` and compacted the function based on the answers provided.

I also renamed the function to a more appropriate name to reflect the fact that it can be used to check the existence of both functions and subroutines.

```
Function ProcExists(ByVal ProcName)

 On Error Resume Next
  Set ProcName = GetRef(ProcName)
  ProcExists   = (Err.Number = 0)
  Err.Clear
 On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```