# Check if an Object exists in VBScript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, object

I'm maintaining a Classic ASP app written in VB Script by an outside company long, long ago.

I have an array of imagefile paths, like so:

```
dim banners, arrKeys, i
set banners=CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
banners.Add "banner1.jpg", "http://www.somelink.com"
banners.Add "banner2.jpg", "http://www.somelink.com"
banners.Add "banner3.jpg", "http://www.somelink.com"
```

This will exist ONLY on pages that have banner ads. There is some standard code that iterates through this list in an include file (common to all pages).

```
If Not banners Is Nothing then 
  ' then loop through the Dictionary and make a list of image links
End if
```

The problem is that if `banners` is not instantiated on the page (it's not on all pages), I get a `Can't find object` error

What's the proper way to check if an object exists in VB Script?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Replace

```
If Not banners Is Nothing then
```

and use

```
If IsObject(banners) Then
```

Your other code you can then place into an include file and use it at the top of your pages to avoid unnecessary duplication.

I tested my snippets above with `Option Explicit` on/off and didn't encounter errors for either version, regardless of whether `Dim banners` was there or not.

Comment: @Atømix: I forgot to check this question again; did it work for you? :-)

Comment: Yes, it did! Thanks. VB6 is a wonderful world of interestingness.

Comment: `IsEmpty` would be better than `IsObject` (although it does appear to work)

Comment: in my case I added also ``and not IsNull(banners)``

Answer (score 32):

`IsObject` could work, but `IsEmpty` might be a better option - it is specifically intended to check if a variable exists or has been initialised.

To summarize:

- [`IsEmpty(var)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cs4befa(v=vs.84).aspx) will test if a variable exists (without Object Explicit), or is initialised
- [`IsNull(var)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbchw6hz(v=vs.84).aspx) will test if a variable has been assigned to [`Null`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8tbc79x(v=vs.84).aspx)
- [`var Is Nothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ake1y5wx(v=vs.84).aspx) will test if a variable has been `Set` to [`Nothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8tbc79x(v=vs.84).aspx), but will throw an error if you try it on something that isn't an object
- [`IsObject(var)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f3htkba(v=vs.84).aspx) will test if a variable is an object (and will apparently still return `False` if `var` is [`Empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8tbc79x(v=vs.84).aspx)).

Answer (score 6):

If a variable is declared, but not initialized, its value will be `Empty`, which you can check for with the `IsEmpty()` function:

```
Dim banners
If IsEmpty(banners) Then
    Response.Write "Yes"
Else
    Response.Write "No"
End If
' Should result in "Yes" being written
```

`banners` will only be equal to `Nothing` if you explicitly assign it that value with `Set banners = Nothing`.

You will have problems, though, with this technique if you have `Option Explicit` turned on (which is the recommendation, but isn't always the case).  In that case, if `banners` hasn't been `Dim`ed and you try to test `IsEmpty(banners)`, you will get a runtime error.  If you don't have `Option Explicit` on, you shouldn't have any problems.

edit: I just saw this [related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098441/how-to-tell-whether-a-variable-in-asp-has-been-declared/4099391#4099391) which might help, too.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, `banners` hasn't been `dim`med in pages without banners.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat related is `IsMissing()` to test if an optional parameter was passed, in this case an object, like this:

```
Sub FooBar(Optional oDoc As Object)

    'if parameter is missing then simulate it
    If IsMissing(oDoc) Then Dim oDoc as Object: oDoc = something

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of IsEmpty, Is Object, IsNull work with the "Option Explicit" Setting, as stealthyninja above has misleadingly answered.
The single way i know is to 'hack' the 'Option Explicit' with the 'On Error Resume Next' setting, as Tristan Havelick nicely does it here:
[Is there any way to check to see if a VBScript function is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921364/is-there-any-way-to-check-to-see-if-a-vbscript-function-is-defined)

Comment: I believe that's to check if a function is defined, where the above is just for checking if a simple variable exists yet. Interesting question though!

Comment: Yeah, IsObject on an undeclared variable with Option Explicit throws error '800a01f4' - Variable is undefined for me, so have to use on error...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least `dim banners` on every page.

Don't you have a `head.asp` or something included on every page?

Comment: There is... however it's the page the specifies the banners and the "work" is done in the htmlhead.inc... so for pages that have banners I need to set the variable BEFORE the head. It's confusing, I know. I'll be glad when I don't have to maintain it.