# How to check if object is inside Application object

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I thought this would be easy but the following code gives...

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
>
> Object required: 'Application(...)'
>
> /include/setup.asp, line 7

```
Function getConnectionString

    Dim connectionString

    Set connectionString = Application("ConnString")

    If connectionString Is Nothing Then

        Set connectionString = loadConnectionString

        Application.Lock
        Application("ConnString") = connectionString
        Application.Unlock

    End If

    getConnectionString = connectionString

End Function
```

`loadConnectionString` is another function.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if an Object exists in VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100506/check-if-an-object-exists-in-vbscript)

Comment: This one... Set connectionString = Application("ConnString")

Comment: Issue is `Application("ConnString")` contains a connection `string` not an `object` so `Set` should not be used. Only use `Set` to store object instances in variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is `connectionString` variable is being treated as an `Object` when it in fact contains a `string`.

`Set` should only be used to store `Object` variables, this goes for `Application("varname")` style variables as well. Remove the `Is Nothing` check as this also refers to `Object` variables and replace it with a `Len(connectionString) < 1` check.

```
Function getConnectionString() 
    Dim connectionString
    connectionString = Application("ConnString")

    If Len(connectionString & "") < 1 Then
        'loadConnectionString() should return a string not an Object
        'may need to be amended.
        connectionString = loadConnectionString()
        Application.Lock
        Application("ConnString") = connectionString
        Application.Unlock
    End If
    getConnectionString = connectionString
End Function
```